# TSQL CASE statement with no matching comparator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I need too make a CASE statement between two databases with no like data points between the two tables except for one varchar field that will have the correct ID number in the title text.  This is the CASE code that I have currently.

```
CASE WHEN sg.lListingNumber in (SELECT c.ListingName
                                FROM CampDB.dbo.tblCampgrounds c, Visitors.dbo.VCAMPS_GLOBAL g
                                WHERE c.ListingName like '%g.lListingNumber%')
     THEN 'YES'
     ELSE 'NO'
END
```

Let me know if there is any further info that I can provide for you.

Comment: Can you join them by this criterion?

Comment: And probably it should be `'%' + g.lListingNumber + '%'`. And probably `CAST(g.lListingNumber as nvarchar(max))`.

Comment: That subselect is quite strange. It is using archaic join syntax that was replaced over 20 years ago. It also doesn't seem to have any bearing on the outer table (sg).

Comment: Sorry Sean, the sg. table is referencing a table out in the larger query, this is only the one part of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery below might be what you're after. I will echo what others said in that you should try to avoid doing this with a correlated subquery and instead rewrite this into your main query as a left join to the tblCampgrounds table.

I also omitted the Visitors.dbo.VCAMPS_GLOBAL table as I couldn't see what it had to do with the subquery in the casestatement

```
CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM CampDB.dbo.tblCampgrounds c
        WHERE c.[ListingName] LIKE '%'  + sg.lListingNumber + '%'
    )
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```